# Greasemonkey script to modify URL not working?

Tags: greasemonkey

I just tried to make this script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Link Bypasser Script
// @include *http://onion.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var oldUrl  = window.location;

var newURL  = "http://localhost:8887/processor.php?link=" + oldUrl;
window.location.replace (newURL);
```

I "inlcude" more urls, but I don't think that's relevant to show, anyway, this script I thought would turn, for example, `http://onion.com/4GUTDTA` into `http://localhost:8887/processor.php?link=http://onion.com/4GUTDTA`, but nothing happens:

Before this I tried:

```
var oldUrlPath  = window.location.path;
```

with:

```
+ "http://localhost:8887/processor.php?link=" + oldUrlPath
```

Which did modify it, however, but it only added that link before the path, which makes sense, because I used `window.location.path`. I also tried to use

```
 var oldUrl  = window.location.href;
```

which did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldUrl  = window.location.href;
var newURL  =  "http://localhost:8887/processor.php?link=" + oldUrl

window.location.replace (newURL);
```

Comment: I don't understand how this could be correct. It adds the search and hash parts twice to the new URL.

Comment: @trincot do you have to call decodeURIComponent() before calling window.location.replace ? Also, i removed the additional search and hash parts

Answer (score 0):

You should encode a string with [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before you append it to a URL:

```
var oldUrl  = window.location.href;
var newURL  = "http://localhost:8887/processor.php?link=" 
              + encodeURIComponent(oldUrl);
window.location.replace (newURL);
```

Comment: I don't know if it has to do with your code or not, but nothing still happens. There's likely something wrong in the beggining.

Comment: I would like to understand why it does not work for you. I have replicated this on my machine with GreaseMonkey, and it works perfectly. The accepted answer does not work well as it duplicates the URL arguments. Do you use a `@grant` in the GreaseMonkey header? I assumed not, because it is not in the question.